Convection or Advection term in the Absolute flux of a chemical species
I am confused as I have been reading on mass transport on multiple sources and they seem to use "advection" and "convection" interchangeably in the equation for the absolute flux of a species:
$$\vec{n}_i = \vec{j}_i +\rho\vec{v}$$
All references I have come across refer to $\vec{j}$ as the diffusion transport component, but some refer to $\rho\vec{v}$ as convection while others refer to it as advection.
Which description is right, as far as I had understood convection and advection are def not the same?

Aren't the same, but don't make a difference here.

Convection vs diffusion or convection vs advection? // Advection is a particular type of convection with geometrical meaning of convection directed here from some other place. Both terms are used in meteorology as well, in context of motion of air.

@Poutnik Thank you for your comment, I have corrected the title. I have read that convection is usually diffusion + advection; however, in this equation the references I can find refer to $\rho \vec{v}$ as advection (and in others as convection), so what is it truly?

wikipedia.org - Advection#Distinction_between_advection_and_convection

@Poutnik But in the context of this equation, are they synonymous or are they not? I am inclined to consider them synonymous in that context, but when I think of the material derivative, it was a "convective acceleration" could i call this "advective acceleration" ?  I have not seen any text use that latter term.

Advection of mass, molar amount or concentration via diffusion or via convection of media.

The term advection in transport phenomena is generally introduced in the definition of material derivative of a scalar magnitude $B$ is
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{D}B}{\mathrm{D}t} =
  \underbrace{\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}}_\text{term I} +
  \underbrace{\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}v_x +
              \frac{\partial B}{\partial y}v_y +
              \frac{\partial B}{\partial z}v_z}_\text{term II} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
The first term is the rate of change of $B$ with respect to time at a fixed point. The second term is the advection, i.e. the change of $B$ with respect to the "advection" from one point to another where $B$ will change. Advection just means 'fluid motion'. In simple terms, the physical property $B$ (for instance, the concentration of cadmium in water) sits over a river. The river moves, so the concentration changes as we imagine that the physical property 'sits' over a background that moves.
Eq. (1) is not restricted to scalar magnitudes. It can be applied to vector magnitudes. If you are familiar with tensor notation, Eq. (1) for the velocity becomes
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{D}\underline{v}}{\mathrm{D}t} =
  \frac{\partial \underline{v}}{\partial t} +
  \underbrace{\underline{v} \cdot \underline{\underline{\nabla v}}}_
  {\text{term III}}
  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Strange as it is, term III represents the advection for the velocity field.
The term in your Eq. (1) which is $\rho \mathbf{v}$ does not have the form of an advection term. But this usually happens when talking, so 'anything' that accompanies the velocity by multiplication tends to be associated with advection, as we think that the physical property is changing along space with the motion of the fluid.
In transport phenomena, there is no fixed name for that magnitude. We generally call it the flux resulting from the bulk motion of the fluid. Let us name this magnitude $\mathbf{B}_j$ and $\mathbf{v}_j$ the velocity of species $j$. In terms of concentrations or mass density the former becomes
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{B}_j = C_j\mathbf{v} =
  C_j\frac{\sum_j c_j\mathbf{v}_j}{\sum_j c_j} &&
  \mathbf{B}_j = \rho_j\mathbf{v} =
  \rho_j\frac{\sum_j \rho_j\mathbf{v}_j}{\sum_j \rho_j} \tag{3,4}
\end{align}
The velocity $\mathbf{v}$ in Eq. (3) is the molar average velocity, and $\mathbf{v}$ in Eq. (4) is the mass average velocity. These equations can be derived and are not definitions.
In the context of electrochemistry, the term $\rho \mathbf{v}$ is always stated as the convection in Nernst-Planck's equation for dilute solution theory, and has the same nature as your equation in your post.

Thank you very much for your answer. I was introduced to the advective term of the material derivative as "the convective term". Would you say advection and convection are used as synonyms for mass transport, while in heat transfer I've seen that convection stands for motion of a flow that 'carries away' heat (usually by means of a density gradient) and advection refers to the bulk motion of a fluid  (usually by means of a pressure gradient).

@RMS Sorry for the late reply... I understand your question, but I will be more accurate if you give me the following information: what is the name of the course in which you were given these terms?

No worries! I was given that naming convention on "Heat and Mass Transfer" and "Fundamentals of Fluid Dynamics", in those courses I was introduced to the 'Material' derivative, which was broken into the local change and the "convective" change.
